# Typescript: how to correctly declare type alias in globals.d.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor, angular-promise

I want to declare a type within the globals.d.ts file so that I can call a shorthand type.

```
declare type Promise<string> = protractor.promise.Promise<string>;
```

The following used to be fine within my typescript project.  However, recently this line has been producing the following **error: Type parameter name cannot be 'string'**.  This may have been caused by a TS upgrade.  I realize that if I change my declared type to Promise or something without the type, this fixes the issue, but I want to understand why this error occurrs.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you intending to create a generic type alias? That is what you have.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, and I am using Typescript 2.0.6

Comment: I'm not sure why it's illegal to shadow `string` in this context but using a different name for the type argument will resolve the error and also be more readable. However it's a bad idea to create an alias that clashes with a global such as `Promise`.

Comment: That is correct, I realize that changing the name of the type resolves the error.  However, I'm wondering why this is the case.

Comment: I did some digging and I believe the reasons are related to the discussion around the pull request which introduce support for generic type aliases https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above declaration is incorrect.  To correctly declare a type alias:

```
declare type Promise<T> = protractor.promise.Promise<T>;
```

This would allow

```
Promise<string>
```

to be used throughout the application, once globals.d.ts was imported.

Generics information can be found: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html